# How can I stop the arguments being printed as output in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to node.js and was trying to calculate the sum while taking arguments from console. Below is my code:

```
console.log(process.argv);
var arr= process.argv;
var sum=0;
for(var i=2; i< arr.length;i++){
sum= sum + Number(arr[i]);
}

console.log(sum);
```

When I ran the program I am getting below output:

```
[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'D:\\NodeJs\\hello.js',
  '16',
  '2' ]
18
```

How can I get only 18(here) as an output?

Comment: Output is done by `console.log()`. So have a look at how many and where you have such statements.

Comment: Remove first line i.e. `console.log(process.argv);`

Comment: the output is correct!

Comment: Please do correct tagging. You asked a JavaScript question, not a Java one!

Comment: Just remove the first `console.log` I mean **THE ONE ON THE BLOODY FIRST LINE**. Still don't get it? Ok, Ok! Remove this from your code: `console.log(process.argv);`.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I know theoutput is correct. I don't want this output, just needed help over the code.

Comment: Ooops silly me:P. Thanks for the help. Got the correct answer.

Comment: @user3003512 You'd better get some sleep!

Answer (score 2):

Delete the first console.log :

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

Your code should be like this :

```
var arr= process.argv;
var sum=0;
for(var i=2; i< arr.length;i++){
sum= sum + Number(arr[i]);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Easy points hein? Enjoy!!!

Comment: Yep ! But I think that the post will be deleted anyways !

Comment: Even so, you'll still have the points.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, I'm newbie. Well, good for me then